# How do I increase the target size of a custom-checkbox in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using forms inside list items in bootstrap 4 and have been using `<a href class="stretched-link">` and a small event handler inside my form controls to make the entire `<li>` clickable, instead of just the small label and checkbox. `stretched-link` increases the target to the nearest relatively positioned item.

Unfortunately compared to the standard controls the nicer `custom-checkbox` uses relative positioning and breaks `stretched-link` so that the click target is only the label text.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can disable relative positioning on the custom control, but that breaks is formatting. How should I make the entire `<li>` control the checkbox?

Comment: what do you mean by "breaking formatting"? can you share a screenshot?

Comment: It just changes the position of the checkbox and label if relative positioning is disabled on those elements